# How do I connect one CSS file as a stylesheet to multiple PHP files in different places for a blog type website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I have a blog type website I am currently making that will have different pages in different folders

like for example, the index.php file is:
C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\index.php and a section file could be

C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\section\section-title.php

C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\section\section-title\section-articles

The stylesheet path is: C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\stylesheets\index.css

I'm looking to get one stylesheet to communicate with both of the php files mentioned above with the one index.css file. What can be done to accomplish this? There will be more files like the examples above where php files are a layer or two below the index.php file.

I apologize if enough information was not given, I am a bit new to webcoding so if a clarification is needed, I can provide more information

I'm open to using whatever is needed to get this accomplished. The website I am creating is using HTML, CSS, Javascript, PHP and Bootstrap 5

---

I'll also add for reference that I happen to have two php documents that I use to link my head code and my navbar code into the other php documents such as index.php. I'll list out how this is done. If it's possible, I would like the index.css document to be able to be linked through the bolded code below in the main-head.php document.

Code to link into document:

```php
<?=include 
    ("C:xampp\htdocs\dashboard\head-code\main-head.php")  
?>
```

main-head.php code:

```php
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Website Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets\index.css">
<base href="https://indianrivernews.us/" target="_blank">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\randomimages.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi! If I understand you want to have access to all addictions on all pages.  You can achieve this by putting all the dependencies in main-head.php as you wrote. And to access them on each page, you need to indent `<?php include "/head-code/main-head.php"; ?>` at the top of the pages.  Of course, you'll need to pay attention to the depth of each page when inserting the common header.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the css file to your main php file like index.php with link tag and use the sections php files with include in your index.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your main-head.php is referring to the correct file path.

It's looking in the head-code directory for a "stylesheets/index.css"

Try "../stylesheets.index.css" instead.

I hope I understood your problem right and this works!